# Fit a Google Chart PIE with exact measures

Tags: google-visualization

I need to fit a PIE to a width of 300px and seems impossible with the Google Chart.

I'm actually using this code:

```
<script type="text/javascript">
  function drawVisualization() {
    // Create and populate the data table.
    var data = new google.visualization.DataTable();
    data.addColumn('string', 'Task');
    data.addColumn('number', 'Hours per Day');
    data.addRows(5);
    data.setValue(0, 0, 'a');
    data.setValue(0, 1, 11);
    data.setValue(1, 0, 'b');
    data.setValue(1, 1, 2);
    data.setValue(2, 0, 'c');
    data.setValue(2, 1, 2);
    data.setValue(3, 0, 'd');
    data.setValue(3, 1, 2);
    data.setValue(4, 0, 'e');
    data.setValue(4, 1, 7);

    // Create and draw the visualization.
    new google.visualization.PieChart(document.getElementById('visualization')).
        draw(data, {width: 300, height: 300, legend: 'none', chartArea: {left:0,top:0,bottom:0,right:0}});
  }


  google.setOnLoadCallback(drawVisualization);
</script>
```

And the generated result is the next, where the `<iframe />` generated has a width and height of 300px but is far away from using all the space.

How I can solve that?

[image]

Answer (score 4):

I also had your problem, and i found the solution:

```
chart.draw(data, {tooltipText: 'percentage', legend: 'none', width: 400, height: 400, chartArea: {width:400, height:400, left:9,top:9,bottom:0,right:0}});
```

Try this piece of Javascript Code.
BTW. Google API Sucks.